# Data storing issue into plist file

Tags: ios, iphone, plist

Once plist is created data storing start automatically, but after some time it automatically stop storing data in plist. But once when i kill app and restart again, it will start again as previously mention and cycle goes on...

Here is my code

```
- (void)saveLocationsToPlist:(NSMutableDictionary*)mdictPlist {


    NSString *plistName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LocationArray.plist"];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDir, plistName];

    NSMutableDictionary *savedProfile = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
    NSLog(@"ADD LOCATION TIME : %@",[NSDate date]);
    NSLog(@"ADD LOCATION DATA : %@",mdictPlist);

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath]){
        BFLog(@"applicationDocumentsDir Not exists");
        fullPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LocationArray.plist"] ];

    }

    if (!savedProfile) {
        savedProfile = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        self.myLocationArrayInPlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    } else {
        self.myLocationArrayInPlist = [savedProfile objectForKey:@"LocationArray"];
    }

    if(mdictPlist) {
        if(self.myLocationArrayInPlist == nil){
            self.myLocationArrayInPlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }

        [_myLocationArrayInPlist addObject:mdictPlist];
        [savedProfile setObject:_myLocationArrayInPlist forKey:@"LocationArray"];
    }


    if (![savedProfile writeToFile:fullPath atomically:FALSE]) {
        BFLog(@"Couldn't save LocationArray.plist savedProfile :- %@ \n Location Data :- %@ \n fullPath:-%@",savedProfile,mdictPlist,fullPath);

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *directory = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@""];
        NSError *error = nil;
        for (NSString *file in [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", directory, file]);
            if([file isEqualToString:@"LocationArray.plist"]){
                BOOL success = [fm removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", directory, file] error:&error];
                if (!success || error) {
                    // it failed.
                    BFLog(@"Delete error : %@",error);

                }
                else {
                    [self saveLocationsToPlist:myLocationDictInPlist];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea about this issue.

Comment: How does it stop? Do you get an error message / log entry, or something?

Comment: i dont get any message and log entry, just i get Couldn't save LocationArray.plist savedProfile message only

Comment: Please change the call `writeToFile:atomically:` to `writeToURL:error:` and check the returned `NSError` object

Comment: Ok i will try with this